# Data manipulation - Very difficult to title

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2K8R2 which is loaded with data from text files that list items we are printing materials for. I have a view on top of the table that executes once for each file that has been loaded. I need to surface a column that answers the question "Which of these items has already been processed and when?" (The query that determines this would only look back x number of days by default.) This would all be very simple if it were based only on the data in the given row, but I need the result to display ALL the items, and (ideally, but not required) to only display it on row number 3 (there is no row number 1 or 2. This is static data, not dynamically assigned by SQL).

For example, I have the data below in a table (extra space for ease of reading):

```
item   filename   rownumber    date
A      fileA.txt     3       10/25/2015
B      fileA.txt     4       10/25/2015
C      fileA.txt     5       10/25/2015

D      fileB.txt     3       10/26/2015
A      fileB.txt     4       10/26/2015
C      fileB.txt     5       10/26/2015
E      fileB.txt     6       10/26/2015
```

Ideally, when the view executes for fileB.txt, I want it to display this (only on row 3):

```
item   filename   rownumber    date      newcol
D      fileB.txt     3       10/26/2015  A,C processed 10/25/2015
A      fileB.txt     4       10/26/2015
C      fileB.txt     5       10/26/2015
E      fileB.txt     6       10/26/2015
```

Or, if necessary, display it on every row:

```
item   filename   rownumber    date      newcol
D      fileB.txt     3       10/26/2015  A,C processed 10/25/2015
A      fileB.txt     4       10/26/2015  A,C processed 10/25/2015
C      fileB.txt     5       10/26/2015  A,C processed 10/25/2015
E      fileB.txt     6       10/26/2015  A,C processed 10/25/2015
```

Note that there may or may not be anything to list, if none of the items in fileB.txt have been processed in the last x days. Also, the same item may be processed more than once in a single day, not just on subsequent days as above. I've played around a bit with some sub queries using outer joins, and gave some thought to a function, but I seem to hit a wall with each potential solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: output is kindof strange.. wouldnt it make more sense to just put the date the Item was processed on the same row as the Item?

Comment: It has to do with how the data is used downstream.  Wherever the row number is 3, a banner page is printed showing whatever is in the new column on that row, so that value has to show all the item values that were processed previously.  I know this is really strange, but it's how it has to be set up.  I should add that the date it was processed is the date field above, so it already does exist on that row, but it must also be read historically to put it in the new column.

Comment: What was the wall you hit with a sub-query?   A sub-query should be able to do this just fine.   If you post your sub-query attempt, we should be able to debug it.